# Python Quadratic loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm having a hard time understanding loops in python. I want to create a loop that continuously prompts the user for the inputs a,b,c, then calculates the answer, displays it and then plots it. My code only executes the statements once. [This is how id like the code to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ljt.png)

The loop should end only via prompt from the user. My main problem is I can't get the loop to run continuously.

```
import pylab
import pylab
import math

xs=[]
ys=[]

x0=-4.0
x1=+4.0
x=x0
n=500

dx=(x1-x0)/n

a= input("Enter a: ")
b = input("Enter b: ")
c= input("Enter c: ")

a=int(a)
b=int(b)
c=int(c)

while x<=x1:
xs.append(x)
y=(a*x**2)+(b*x+c)
ys.append(y)
x+=dx

pylab.plot(xs,ys,"rx-")
print(xs)
print(ys)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to indent all the statements after your while loops and a single iteration version of your program should work. Proper indentation is critical in python.  Lots of sites talk about python indentation (see [here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3) for example).  You were also missing the outer loop that would allow it to loop indefinitely.

Additionally you can clear the graph after each iteration.

```
import pylab
import math

xs=[]
ys=[]

x0=-4.0
x1=+4.0
x=x0
n=500

dx=(x1-x0)/n

while True:

  a=input("Enter a: ")
  b=input("Enter b: ")
  c=input("Enter c: ")

  a=int(a)
  b=int(b)
  c=int(c)

  xs=[]
  ys=[]
  x=x0  
  while x<=x1:
    xs.append(x)
    y=(a*x**2)+(b*x+c)
    x+=dx
    ys.append(y)

  pylab.plot(xs,ys,"rx-")
  print(xs)
  print(ys)
  pylab.show()
  pylab.clf()
```

Comment: Sorry, the copy and paste kind of messed up the indentation, but my question was how do i have to loop plot,then return back to prompting the user. i tried nesting a if loop(having theprompt be in the while loop, then having the plot in the if loop),but it doesnt work

Comment: What do you get if you run the code above?  Does it work?

Comment: yes it worked, i also finished the program. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to do your indentation correctly in the while-loop.
Second, your while loop only create the lists, `xs` and `ys`. That's why you can't keep the prompt and plot running again and again. So you have to use another loop to repeat your code above. Here is an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
def interactiveQPlot():
    xs=[]
    ys=[]

    x0=-4.0
    x1=+4.0
    x=x0
    n=500

    dx=(x1-x0)/n

    a= input("Enter a: ")
    b = input("Enter b: ")
    c= input("Enter c: ")

    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    c=int(c)

    while x<=x1:
        xs.append(x)
        y=(a*x**2)+(b*x+c)
        ys.append(y)
        x+=dx

    plt.plot(xs,ys,"rx-")
    print(xs)
    print(ys)
    plt.show()

while True:
    interactiveQPlot()
```